# Cannot get WebStorm to recognize gsap/TweenLight library?

Tags: webstorm, gsap

I'm using `TweenLite` from a CDN, like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
```

When I reference `TweenLight`, WebStorm says it's unresolved.  I have gone into the Libraries interface and checked "TweenLite" which was already there. I also added "gsap" from the download section.  It still says Unresolved.

I also tried all the steps above with TweenMax.  Same problem.

[image]

**How can I get WebStorm to recognize GSAP?**

Comment: `"TweenLite"` library was likely created by downloading file `TweenLite.min.js` from CDN reference. But unfortunately minified files can't be used as libraries - the IDE needs a debug, non-compressed version to be able to provide a completion. Downloading `@types/gsap` should work, but unfortunately `Tween.d.ts` exports `TweenLite` as `gsap.TweenLite`, and the IDE can't resolve it by short name. Adding `/**
 * @typedef {gsap.TweenLite} TweenLite
 */
` to the top of your .js file should help

Comment: How can I *un*download it from the CDN reference (which I did, in fact, do)? Would that fix the issue?

Comment: And unfortunately, adding that line did not help.

Comment: Just clear the checkbox next to `Tweenlite` in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`, or press **Remove** button to delete it